# Loading External Picture in air for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, file-upload, air

I need load images from a folder in application directory created in sd Card of mobile android

This is working in PC, but not in mobile version

Some solution ?

```
var imagesFin:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("appImages/");
var files:Array = imagesFin.getDirectoryListing();

 for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++){


  var picLoader = new Loader();
  picLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadPicture);
  picLoader.load(new URLRequest(files[i].nativePath));

 }
 function loadPicture(event:Event):void {

 var imgAtual = event.target.content;
 ContainerImagesList.addChild(imgAtual);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add a error event listener?

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var myFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(YOUR_PATH);

myFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCompleteHandler)
myFileStream.openAsync(myFile, FileMode.READ);

function fileCompleteHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    myFileStream.readBytes(bytes);

    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    loader.loadBytes(bytes);

    function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        addChild(Bitmap(loader.content));
        myFileStream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCompleteHandler);
        myFileStream.close();
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS I never use resolvePath. I just use a relative url like "images/photo.jpg" and it works  perfectly on any iOS device.

Instead of resolvePath you could also use URL schemes. It's a lot simpler "app:/images/photo.jpg" or "app-storage:/settings/prefs.xml".

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html

This is what I do to get all images in my image file cache

```
var imageFolder:File = new File("app:/img");
var getfiles:Array = imageFolder.getDirectoryListing();
```